# Xcode 7.3 very slow typing in one class

Tags: xcode, swift, performance

I've a strange problem with Xcode 7.3.

From one build to another the typing in one swift-class is extremly slow.
I'm not able to work.

I have two ViewControllers and I only have the problem in the first...
Class SecondViewController is fast as it should be...

Almost reinstalled Xcode and deleted everything from libary.
Tried this also: defaults write com.apple.dt.XCode IDEIndexDisable 1
And this: Build Settings --> Swift Compiler - Code generation --> Optimization Level --> Debug --> Fast, Whole Module Optimization
No success.

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with your code in this class, causing the Swift parser to bog down.

Comment: commented whole code out in this class.. no success..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

Dont use multiline comments!
It perfoms the parser down!
@T.Els Thank You!

Can someone explain me why?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if this answer could help others experiencing same issue. I was also experiencing slow typing but i could see it in every class, problem on my end was that i had many tabs and sub tabs opened in Xcode

Closing most of tabs and sub tabs improved typing but issue was still not gone.

After quitting Xcode, I went to Go--> Library --> Developer --> Xcode --> Derived Data and deleted is contents.

It fixed issue of slow typing in Xcode.